# keystroke logger

Tags: packet-sniffer

I have just started a networking module in college and am really interested in this area, and would like to continue in this career path. I have tried to get an answer from my lecturer but she cant give me one, so here it is for you.

Is it possible to intercept information across a wirless network (which i have access to) as in IM messages/ emails etc, which is being sent by another pc on the network (home)?

If so is there a commercially available program to do this.

sorry if this is a stupid question, but im really interested to find out ASAP.

Comment: Interested to find out ASAP, intercept across wireless the IM's/emails to a system on a home network...doesn't exactly sound like you're doing this with the best of (legitimate) motivations.

Comment: This is really more of a [security](http://security.stackexchange.com) question, and a bad fit anyway because... well, *Google*!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to intercept information across a wirless network
>   (which i have access to) as in IM messages/ emails etc, which is being
>   sent by another pc on the network (home)?

Assuming they're not using SSL, yes.
And it's not hard.

> If so is there a commercially available program to do this.

Yes. And a bunch of free ones. And you can do it yourself with tcpdump / ethereal / wireshark if you're sufficiently motivated.

---

> I have tried to get an answer from my lecturer but she cant give me
>   one, so here it is for you.

If your lecturer is ***unable*** to answer they are not worth what you're paying for the class.
If they are ***unwilling*** to answer, see Bart's comment on your question.